# Bokeh Error EMPTY_LAYOUT

Tags: python, ubuntu, bokeh

I've written a python script that generates a number of bokeh plots. It has worked well on Windows 7, Python 3.5. When I run the same script on Ubuntu, Python 3.4, I get the following error:

> (EMPTY_LAYOUT): Layout has no children: VBox, ViewModel: VBox, ref_id:19d72e44-cacd-4bbb-a480-0d74bd8c38df

How can I fix this?

Comment: It would help to have an [**_MCVE_**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: More than "would help", it's *impossible* to speculate about anything, or provide any sort of assistance, until you provide  the code you used that generated the error.

Comment: Working on an MCVE now